# Why is Twitter's "Discover" using someone I've unfollowed?

Tags: twitter

I've recently unfollowed someone on Twitter, but she's still on a private list that I have. However, Twitter is still using her when suggesting tweets in the "Discover" tab.

Do I need to remove her from the list, or just wait a bit so that Twitter will update who to use in "Discover"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no longer getting tweets based on the person I unfollowed, even though I still have her on a private twitter list. It must have been a "wait a bit" scenario.